# What are the restrictions of running a completely offline chatbot?

Tags: android, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, offline

first post. 
 I'm a chatbot conversation designer/digital strategist in the international development sector and my client is interested in having a chatbot within their Android period-tracker app. The app is designed for users in low connectivity areas with low access to data, hence the offline requirement. Initially it would just allow users to chat to an avatar and get information on various educational topics, but we might want to use it more creatively down the line.

I've gathered having a chatbot that runs entirely offline within an app is technically feasible (right?), but I'd like to understand a bit more about the restrictions/downsides of implementing something like this. The obvious one to me is the size I would imagine the app would need to be to support this which is a sure fire way to get your app deleted when you're using a crappy Android phone which many of our users will be.

What else? Any advice is appreciated!

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is sort of a opinion request type question which may be off-topic. App size is a concern as well as supporting multiple languages in addition to how updates can be done in a low bandwidth environment. Be aware that in certain low bandwidth environments, a SMS/web service may be more appropriate than a on-device app. StackOverflow works best with specific programming questions along with showing related code/errors and what you've tried.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems, not a forum to probe for open-ended opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running a bot offline without being dependent on any cloud based service is totally feasible. The app would need to establish the following.

For brevity I am using *Online Bot* to refer to a bot app that is based on an online service. *Offline Bot* for a bot app that is based on an offline or on-device bot development platform.

### Requirements

- Knowledge-base (containing `Intents`, `Entities` and `Contexts`) has to be saved within the app. `Entities` contribute (though in kilobytes maybe) to your app size. For example if your bot is to recognize a *country name*, you would need to store all the country names within the bot's knowledge-base.
- Natural Language  domain-specific information like dictionaries, thesaurus and additional word information. *These may not be passed on to your deployment/published app after a model is generated*.
- **Language Model** generated by the app would reside within the app package. *This is going to be the main role player in your app size*.

### Online

Low bandwidth data connectivity shouldn't be much of a problem as the overhead of communicating with services like the following is not that high:

- [DialogFlow](https://dialogflow.com/)
- [LUIS](https://www.luis.ai/home)
- [WIT.AI](https://wit.ai/)
- [IBM Watson](https://www.ibm.com/watson/how-to-build-a-chatbot)

The above services enable APIs directly via small JSON data exchanges. You can check how much overhead is too much of an overhead for you by looking at their APIs and returned data.

#### Pros and cons

- Online bot would enjoy remote updates to their knowledge-base
- Your online bot data is not secure as anything your users say/type goes to third-party services for response generation.
- Response speed of your bot depends on the performance of the online service you use. Typically shouldn't be a problem on normal networks.
- Your app is useless when not connected to the internet.

### Offline or On-Device

If you are designing a completely offline bot you would need to rely on frameworks or platforms that are designed to fulfill the aforementioned features.

- [OSCOVA](https://oscova.com/) - On-Device bot development platform that I personally have used to create an Android Bot for general customer queries in Xamarin.
- [SIML](https://simlbot.com/) - An XML based knowledge-base authoring language with Machine Learning features.
- [BotSharp](https://botsharp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - Bot development platform by SciSharp
- [Xatkit](https://github.com/xatkit-bot-platform/xatkit) - Java-based chatbot creation platform.

#### Pros and cons

- Your offline bot app would need a new package update (in App Store or Play Store) whenever you wish to add more to its knowledge-base (KB). *Maybe you could send a KB directly to the app when connected online.*
- Your offline bot size is going to be a bit larger in comparison to a bot that uses online services.
- Your bot is always-on as it doesn't require internet to perform tasks or respond to its users.
- Conversation with your bot is extremely secure as the data is not shared to third-party service like in the case of online bots.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this answer with me despite the fact that it was slightly off-topic for stack overflow. Really really appreciate the time spent and clarity of the answer. This will put me in a much better position to advise my client based on specifics rather than my gut feel (and also validating to see it was right). Cheers and have a great day :)