# tabbarview with children tab with many tabs becomes slow to load in home page leads to black screen

Tags: flutter

```html
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Home_G_HX(),
              Physical(),
              Text("1"),
            ],
          ),
```

Home_G_HX and Physical have many widgets so home screen loading becomes slow

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/59785756/19165706. Hope this can help you.

Comment: In simple terms, you can use Dialogflow and hook it up to a node.js server. Implement a chat screen with your app and connect to your nodejs server using socket connection. If you set pre-defined texts to dialogflow, everytime you write something, dialogflow.ai will reply you

Answer (score 1):

**The most effective method to Create a Chatbot Using DialogFlow ?
What is DialogFlow ?**

DialogFlow is an improvement stage made by Google that can assist us with making Chatbots. It depends on NLP (Natural Language Processing) which offers our chatbots the likelihood to be extremely strong.

**What is the ChatBot ?**

A chatBot is a keen program that can cooperate with individuals like a human and serves them in the particular space where it has been made. The chatbot examines the expectation of the client and investigates the reaction that will be more adjusted.

Presently you understand what DialogFlow and chatbot are, we should perceive how we can make a chatbot utilizing Dialogflow.

Note: You ought to have a google account and login in to the Dialogflow stage prior to following these means.

In this article, we will make a chatbot that can serve clients who will believe should do a booking for a room in a Hotel.

**Stage 1. Make an Agent**

An Agent is a smart program inside the chatbot, that program interfaces with the clients or clients.

To make an Agent, go to the left segment of your screen and snap on the main button underneath the Dialogflow logo and go down to the make new specialist button.

From that point onward, the new screen will be stacked, and you will be request to indicate the name of the Agent, the language that it ought to be talk and the time region. As far as I might be concerned, I type reservation-bot for the name and the rest, I leave the default values. From that point onward, you should tap on the CREATE button and DialogFlow will make a specialist for your chatbot.

**Stage 2. Make plans**

Purposes is use by the chatbot to comprehend what the clients or clients need. It's inside the goals that we ought to give to the chatbot the instances of expressions that the clients might ask and a few reactions that the chatbot ought to use to pay all due respects to the clients. We should demonstrate the way that we can make it happen.

Note: When we make another specialist, it accompanies two defaults aims named Default Fallback Intent and Default Welcome Intent

For make another Intent, click on the Create Intent button

From that point onward, you should give the name of your goal. Then, at that point, go to the Training Phrases segment and snap on add preparing phrases. This part concerns the way where you ought to give the case of the expression which addresses the various inquiries that clients might pose to the chatbot. we prescribe giving numerous guides to make your chatbot extremely strong.

For this model, you could accept similar expressions as me.

We have added a few expressions that clients might ask to our chatbot, for your own chatbot, go ahead and add one more expression to work on the force of your chatbot

In this picture, we can see that two articulations are overlined. DialogFlow has recognized these articulations as a substance, truth be told. DialogFlow perceives three kinds of elements like frameworks substances, engineer elements, and meeting substances. this evening and today are perceived as frameworks elements, it alludes to the date or timeframe, this kind of substance is now set in Dialogflow. Later we will make our own elements which will perceive by DialogFlow as Developer substances. For more data, look at this documentation

Presently, we should characterize a Responses that the specialist might use to pay all due respects to clients. Go down to the Response segment and snap on the Add reaction button, and add a few reactions explanations.

**Moving Bot Articles:**

1. How Conversational AI can Automate Customer Service
2. Robotized versus Live Chats: What will the Future of Customer Service Look Like?
3. Chatbots As Medical Assistants In COVID-19 Pandemic
4. Chatbot Vs. Clever Virtual Assistant — What's the distinction and Why Care?

You can see that inside these reactions models there are a few articulations that beginning with the $ image, these articulations are considered as factors that will contain the qualities that clients will make reference to in their inquiries, and that DialogFlow will have perceived as a specific substance. On the picture above, we have three factors, for example, $time-period, $date-time, and $reservation-type. $time-period and $date-time are frameworks substances factors and $reservation-type is a Developer element variable, and that implies $reservation-type ought to be made by the engineer, before that DialogFLow might remember it. After added a few reactions that the specialist ought to utilize, click on the Save button, we will return from this point forward.

Stage 3. Making of substances

In all actuality, substances are catchphrases that assist the Agent with perceiving what the client needs. To make it, simply follow me.

Click on the Entities button

production of substances
After click on the Create Entity button

formation of element
Later, determine the name of the element (you ought to give reservation-type as name of your substance, since you have use it as factor when you gave a few reactions to the specialist). Then, add a substance bed-room and a few equivalents like beneath.

try to check the case Define equivalent words previously, and afterward click on Save button.

The job of equivalent words is that, when clients ought to discuss bed-room, bed or room, all of this ought to allude to the bed-room.

Do likewise with the element reservation-activity and save it.

formation of reservation-activity substance
Presently, we have two elements fit to be utilized.

Stage 4. add our substances inside preparing phrases articulations

back to the booking aim interface and go to the preparation phrases segment.

At the point when you are there, select an articulation, and inside this articulation select the word bed-room like this

Then, at that point, research for @reservation-type

What's more, click on this, and the shade of bed-room will change.

Do exactly the same thing to all the bed-room inside all articulations.

For the words booking, reservation, and save, do exactly the same things however rather than research @reservation-type you will explore @reservation-activity.

adding developper elements inside our preparation expression articulations
Stage 5. Meaning of boundaries and activities

It's not needed, yet now and again, it will be vital to commit the client to provide for the chatbot, some data.

Go down to the Actions and boundaries segment, consistently inside the booking expectation interface. you ought to have this picture underneath.

activity and boundaries
For our chatbot, we need that clients give the booking type and the date of the reservation. Make a point to really look at it.

activities and boundaries
From that point forward, we ought to indicate the brief text that the Agent ought to show to the client when they haven't determined the necessary boundaries. You want to tap on the Define prompts… space on the ideal locations of this segment, in the wake of characterizing brief text, close the container discourse.

for the date-time boundary

characterize brief text for date time boundary
for the booking type boundary

After this, save the plan.

Presently you can test your chatbot.

test segment
You can test your chatbot here.

Stage 6. Coordination on the web stage

reconciliation
Click on the reconciliations button

You can incorporate your chatbot within numerous stages, as Facebook courier, WhatsApp, wire, etc.

For this article, we will pick the Web Demo

coordination demo
click on the connection, and test it once more.

Comment: If you copy a blog post or whatever always mention the source otherwise its a copyright violation

Answer (score 1):

You can use DialogFlow from Google, Luis/Bot-service from Azure etc for cloud based solutions or Rasa-Ai for simpler on-prem solutions. So to get started, build a simple Flutter app that has a text box where you can type something. Once you type, let the content flow to server via an explicit submit button for instance and let the NodeJos server ( or any server ) return you a random message. This is your first phase. You then need to replace the request-response scheme with a chatbot.

An example of a bot using Azure system can be found here: https://github.com/pawanit17/EventBright

Another example that uses socket.io based communication to the clients can be found here:
https://github.com/pawanit17/LetsChat-A-Simple-WebSockets-Chatting-App

Experiment with them.